# Unity remote security vulnerablity risk identified. Is there a patch for beta versions?

Tags: unity, security, hacks

https://unity3d.com/security?utm_campaign=other_emea_announcement_2017-08-18-EMEA-Security-Notification&utm_content=2017-08-17-Global-Editor-Security-Notification&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua

Ok So I got an email with the attached link stating there is vulnerablity been identified and I need to patch Unity. However I had several crashing errors and other errors since I updated to 2017.1 and so I'm currently using the beta b6 version.

On the link, i didnt see a mention of a patch. Am I supposed to use the 2017 patch? Or is there not a patch for this ? (If thats the case, should I uninstall the beta , or just not use it? Or is it safe to use?)

SIDE NOTE: Is this WHY I keep getting the error saying : Failed to connect , you longer own this project, check your network connections ... etc . Im worried I had already been hacked maybe?

Comment: What about this? http://i.imgur.com/dDuBg98.png

Comment: @Tyyppi Yeah i saw that but i dont understand what it is. It turns out any way that them downloads are full reinstalls. So I just removed beta version and installed their new 2017 build. Hopefully the bugs I was getting in the other 2017 are gone too with any luck :)

Comment: [A guy on reddit had a good write up on this](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/6ufcyq/remote_code_execution_security_patch_for_unity/). The mitigation tool will remove the registry key that allows the remote code execution bug to happen. You should be safe after applying it to any version but you lose the ability to click web browser Asset Store links

Comment: thanks for your answers. i went ahead and just done a clean install as I havent got anything majorly important that Im worried to break. But at least your link is here in case anyone else needs it. cheers